# remove logo and text from action bar and replace them with icons

Tags: android

I want to remove my icon logo and text in the action bar and replace it with icons [image]

how to achieve that ?

this is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >



        <item android:id="@+id/add"
          android:icon="@drawable/add"
          android:title="add picture"
          app:showAsAction="always" />

     <item android:id="@+id/ic_action_picture"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_picture"
          android:title="@string/ic_action_picture"
          app:showAsAction="always" />


      <item android:id="@+id/ic_action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/ic_action_search"
          app:showAsAction="always"/>


       <item android:id="@+id/ic_action_person"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_person"
          android:title="@string/ic_action_person"
          app:showAsAction="always" />


</menu>
```

and this is my style.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->

<style name="AppTheme1" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>  
</style> 
     <style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#14a804</item>
    </style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
   </style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">

    <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
    <item name="background">@color/red</item>

</style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to hide the logo and text, add the following to your Activities `onCreate` Method:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

For further customizations like Item alignment have a look [here](http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/android-custom-actionbar/).

Comment: I dont want it programeticly

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is this, remove the action bar from the activity, in the xml create  linear layout alike the action bar on this put all your icons.

The hard way, inflate a xml in your action bar.

I always choose the first option. Regards

Comment: Which one is the best way?

Comment: I believe that to achieve what you want the better way is the easy way, first remove the actionbar with this code: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: Can you display it as full example please ?

Comment: I did it with the first example , I hope it doesnt contain disadvantages .

Comment: Hi! this code it's ok in many cases, specially if you have to modify the action bar, if you need help write me to TW @devferlara Regards